# Punctual VS punctually

Tags: grammar

I see this sentence:” He is never **punctual** going to work; he is always late.

Why not use “punctually”? **go** is a verb, so punctually may be right. That is my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*Punctually going*" is different from *being punctual when you go*. As "punctually" is an adverb, the former would mean that the act of going is punctual, whereas "punctual" is an adjective and describes the person in your example, so the latter would mean that he is punctual about setting off to go.

"Punctually" means at the proper time. It doesn't make sense to describe his "going" as being punctual, because that is his journey. We would normally describe someone's departure or arrival as being "punctual".